# How to use Optional in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a Service which queries for a list of coupons from the database. This service returns an `Optional` to the client.

```
return listOfCoupons.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(listOfCoupons.get(listOfCoupons.size() - 1));
```

And the client of this code uses `Optional` named 'coupons' in the following way:

```
if (coupons.isPresent) {
   save (coupons.get());
}
```

Is this the correct use of `Optional` ?

Comment: how do you mean? it looks fine from afar although the `if` logic check can potentially be "improved" to `coupons.ifPresent(c -> save(c));` but that's ultimately down to taste.

Comment: You can use it in any way you like. Your code is perfectly fine. If you want,  you can make it more "functional" as: `coupons.isPresent(this::save);` (replace this with whichever object save method belong to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of the `Optional<T>` API looks fine from afar as I cannot see any misuse of it. if I were to nitpick and suggest something I would change:

```
if (coupons.isPresent) {
   save (coupons.get());
}
```

to:

```
coupons.ifPresent(c -> save(c)); //or method reference
```

but then again that's down to taste really.